# how do I remove LeftCTRL binding from alt gr key?

Tags: windows, keyboard, registry

I have a laptop with an "alt gr" key in the Right Alt position.
This has an extra binding to the left CTRL key so that, in effect, pressing Alt gr is equivalent to pressing Left CTRL + Alt

Using KeyboardStateView utility, i have found that the following are sent on keypress of Alt gr:

```
17: CTRL key - 0x11;
18: ALT key - 0x12;
162: Left CONTROL Key - 0xa2;
165: Right Menu Key - 0xa5
```

is there any way to remove the binding to '17 - 0x11' AND '162 - 0xa2' WITHOUT disabling normal function of the Left CTRL key?

I think this will need to be done by altering the registry, I've tried a few keyboard remapping utilities but they don't have the level of functionality I need.

It MAY be possible with autohotkey, but I don't know enough about scripting it, have asked on their forum.

Comment: Just to note, the above behavior of the Alt gr key is particular to UK English keyboard layout (and possibly other languages), but NOT US QWERTY layout, where Alt Gr behaves like a normal Alt and doesn't send any extra messages. https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/issues/3641#issuecomment-635522276